# How do I get plot type of a given Axes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix() to get a matrix of histograms and scatter plots.

```
axes = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(recent_grads[['Women', 'Men']], figsize=(10,10))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to iterate over each Axes instance and change its `xlim` and `ylim` if it's a scatter plot.

```
lim_range = (0, recent_grads[['Women', 'Men']].max().max())

@np.vectorize
def set_lims(ax):
    # check if ax is a scatter plot
    ax.set_xlim((lim_range))
    ax.set_ylim((lim_range))
```

Is there any way to get the plot type of an Axes? In this case I know that the scatter plots are in indexes 1 and 2 but I would like to avoid checking for indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as *plot type of an Axes*. An axes can have arbitrary plots in it, e.g. you could plot an image, a scatter plot and a contour plot in the same axes.

You could check if there is a collection inside the axes, which, for a scatter_matrix plot would mean that it is a scatter plot,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

axes = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='hist')

lim_range = (-7, 7)
for ax in axes.flat:
    if len(ax.collections) > 0:
        ax.set_xlim(lim_range)
        ax.set_ylim(lim_range)

plt.show()
```

The drawback of this is that the first y axis and last x axis will stay unchanged this way, as they do not contain a scatter plot. 
Hence you would need to change the xticks for all plots anyways (just put it outside the checking. The yticks of the first yaxis will be more complicated. You would need to take them from some other axis and readjust the ticks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

axes = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='hist')

lim_range = (-7, 7)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlim(lim_range)
    if len(ax.collections) > 0:
        ax.set_ylim(lim_range)

lim1 = axes[0][1].get_xlim()
locs = axes[0][1].yaxis.get_majorticklocs()
locs = locs[(lim1[0] <= locs) & (locs <= lim1[1])]
adj = (locs - lim1[0]) / (lim1[1] - lim1[0])

lim0 = axes[0][0].get_ylim()
adj = adj * (lim0[1] - lim0[0]) + lim0[0]
axes[0][0].yaxis.set_ticks(adj)

if np.all(locs == locs.astype(int)):
    # if all ticks are int
    locs = locs.astype(int)
axes[0][0].yaxis.set_ticklabels(locs)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no generic way to determine what plots an Axes instance has? I noticed that an Axes with a histogram plot has a BarContainer in containers which would also fit bar plots, while Axes with scatter plots will have, like you mentioned,  PathCollection in collections. It doesn't seem like a reliable way to determine which plot types were defined.

Comment: No, the concept of *plots owned by axes* simply does not exist in matplotlib. An axes has children, which are `Artists`. But they do not carry information about who created them and how that was done. As you say, a BarContainer could e.g. have been produced by having called the `hist` or the `bar` command. One could also produce such container manually. So there is no way of knowing for sure the "type of plot". You can only use your knowledge about how a figure is produced to know what could possibly be inside any of the axes.

Comment: If you need more control, it might be an option to create the complete plot yourself.